# Error: ng:areq Bad Argument AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, undefined

I am working on a new portfolio site and want to use AngularJS to display my work and pure css to format layout etc.

I found a useful tutorial that outlined how to structure your app for future scaling and have set up a file tree like so:

[image]

so each component is a basically a mini MVC. I have set up my routes in app.routes.js and organised app.module.js as below:

app.module.js:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'appControllers', 'appResources']);
angular.module('appControllers', ['ngRoute']);
angular.module('appResources', ['ngResource']);
```

app.route.js:

```
angular.module('app')

    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

        'use strict';

        $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'app/components/home/home-view.html',
            controller  : 'HomeCtrl'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'app/components/about/about-view.html',
            controller  : 'AboutCtrl'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'app/components/contact/contact-view.html',
            controller  : 'ContactCtrl'
        });
}]);
```

so this is my set up, for now, I just need to see that each controller for the routes are working and then I will begin adding in my content, but I have hit a hurdle straight away as the controllers for each view are showing as undefined.

Here is an example of a controller, they are all the same at the moment, but with a different message:

```
angular.module('appControllers')

    .controller('AboutCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.message = 'This will be the about page';
    }]);
```

the html is correct and there are no typos, so I am scratching my head as to why this is showing up as an error.

Is this something to do with the way I have my modules set up?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is telling you that your `HomeCtrl` is undefined. You will need to include a `<script src="app/components/home/HomeController.js"></script>` in your `index.html` file to include each of your controllers with this type of app configuration.

If you want to avoid this, you can scaffold your app something like this.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module('appControllers')

        .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.message = 'This will be the home page';
        }])

        .controller('AboutCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.message = 'This will be the about page';
        }]);

})();
```

There is no single "best" way to do something. It is all relative to the needs of your app and preference.

Comment: The tutorial I found suggested this format was best practice. This sounds like a bit of a clunky way eventhough the modules and routes are defined in the header?

Comment: It's personal preference. There are 2 popular ways to create angular apps. The first is how you are doing it currently, creating a directory for each state/route in your app which includes the `.html` and `.js` files. Another popular way is to create 1 module for each components. For example, you would create an `app.controllers` module which would house ALL of your controllers, then an `app.services` module which would house ALL of your services. I tend to prefer the 2nd method for smaller projects.

Comment: So if I create say, 10 different types of page, I would have to include a script tag for each of my controllers? My head tag is going to be pretty big. Is there any other way to ensure that my app controllers are able to pick up each individual controller?

Comment: Another option would be to use `gulp` or `grunt` and create a task which searches for any files in your project directory which include `Controller.js` in their file name, then concatenate them together into a single file. Then you would be able to include that single file in your `index.html`. Otherwise, you will need to include them all manually, and yes you're `<head`> will get large which is not good for initial load time.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I could compile them into one controller.js file with gulp. Yes, I was thinking the load time would be effected by the stacking in the head. Thanks. I'll give it go.